# visual studio code is showing error while running c program

Tags: c, xcode, visual-studio

*(Please insert your question here)*

```
Program 'hello.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:69
+ ... rogramming\" ; if ($?) { gcc hello.c -o hello } ; if ($?) { .\hello }
+                                                                 ~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:69
+ ... rogramming\" ; if ($?) { gcc hello.c -o hello } ; if ($?) { .\hello }
+                                                                 ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Comment: Well, sounds a lot like a Windows fault or something to do with resources on you system at the moment.Try rebooting ? additionally, share some code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your question so that the error codes are formatted. But can you add a question? And post the code that is failing?